# How can I color all numbers in a word document?

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to make a text easier to learn so I am looking to color specific information without having to find each information and formating it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might helps:

```
Sub Changenumbercolour()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "([0-9])"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say: "...without having to find each [sic] information and formatting it." Do you mean you don't want to use the "Find" function in MS Word or that you don't want to manually search for the information? If you mean the latter then you can use the advanced find function.

Comment: Well, I have around 30 years in a history project I gotta learn. So to learn them easier I wanted to color the years. What's up there happend to be the answer.